# NextJS Server-only Render to Reduce Client Bundle Size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js, server-side-rendering

TLDR: Is there a way to signal to NextJS to render a component *only* on the server (and thus only show the pre-rendered HTML on the client)?

Motivation:
The reason I want to do this is because the render function inside of the component in question runs a lot of (synchronous) Javascript. I'd like for this Javascript to **not** be included in the client bundle. My desired behavior is that this component is rendered once on the server and the generated HTML is simply displayed on the client; it should never render on the client.

Things that I've tried / don't work:

1. `getServerSideProps`
   It appears that, even when a page has `getServerSideProps`, it will still send the Javascript code to the client. My assumption is that this occurs because NextJS (incorrectly) assumes that some state update could possibly occur in the component on the client and therefore the client must have access to the Javascript code to render the component in such an event. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here?
2. Static rendering
   The page uses dynamic from the URL (imagine something like the delivery status page of a delivery website; there are hundreds of thousands of different deliveries and so it doesn't make sense for them all to be statically rendered)
3. Conditional Rendering based on `typeof window`
   I don't think this helps with my particular issue as I'd like to skip rendering entirely on the client but still show the component *as it was rendered on the server*

Thanks so much for any and all help!